# Performance difference between 1 query returning n records and n queries returning 1 record?

Tags: performance, amazon-simpledb

With respect to Amazon SimpleDB,

Is there any significant performance difference between

```
select * from mydomain where itemName() in('id1','id2','id3', 'id4')
```

and

```
select * from mydomain where itemName() == 'id1'
select * from mydomain where itemName() == 'id2'
select * from mydomain where itemName() == 'id3'
select * from mydomain where itemName() == 'id4'
```

Comment: Simple algebra. You'll have the answer yourself before anyone answers here.

Comment: I am guessing there would be a performance overhead in running 4 queries. How big is the overhead? Maybe it is negligible for 4 queries. What happens when I run 10k or 100k?

Comment: Thanks for giving half the answer to your question. The other half is, "go find out yourself" what the overhead is.

Comment: No, actually, "it depends", and you'll want to find the answers that are specific to your particular environment.

Answer (score 0):

Starting four whole new queries might be slower than running one which is only a little bit more slower compared to any of the other four.